# Rails Json String Length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to pass JSON to an API, which has the possibility to be fairly long due to including territory codes.  When restricting the territories to 20 or 30, everything works fine, but when extending this to 250, the API call does not take place.  Checking the length of the JSON string, it is around 5000 characters.

The problem only occurs in production, and not in development.  The app is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  When checking logs I get no information at all, as if it just stopped at a certain point and ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing the JSON via GET request, please note the URI in an HTTP request has certain limit. You may want to pass the data as POST.